# Local variable becomes undefined on refresh. Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am working on a chat application. There is a chat.component.ts that connects to a service and grabs 'messages' and 'displayName'.

In the chat.component.html am binding the displayName like this: 
`<p>You are logged in as: {{displayName}}</p>`

This is what the chat.component.ts looks like:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AfService } from '../af.service';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  public newMessage: string;
  public messages: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  public displayName: string;

  constructor(public AF: AfService) {
    this.messages = this.AF.messages;
    this.displayName = this.AF.displayName;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  @ViewChild('scrollMe') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  scrollToBottom(): void {
    try {
      this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    } catch(err) { console.log('Scroll to bottom failed yo!')}
  }

  isMe(email) {
    if(email == this.AF.email)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  sendMessage(){
    this.AF.sendMessage(this.newMessage);
    this.newMessage = '';
  }
}
```

The displayName property in the AfService is being set from a previous component.

Now this is the issue:

When I worked through the application from scratch and log in the displayName is available. However when I refresh the chat.component.html page the displayName becomes undefined. For example if I do console.log(this.AF.displayName) it displays as should, however, if I do console.log(this.displayName) it is undefined.

The interesting thing is that 'messaages' keeps working properly.

I believe that this is more of a conceptual question and I am trying to figure out why this happens and how to fix it. Also I couldn't of a better title for this question.

Update, this is the AfService:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AfService {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  messages: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  displayName: string;
  email: string;

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.messages = this.db.list('messages');
  }

  loginWithGoogle(){
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  };

  logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  };

  sendMessage(text) {
    var message = {
      message: text,
      displayName: this.displayName,
      email: tis.email,
      timestamp: Date.now()
    };
    this.messages.push(message);
  };

  getDisplayName() {
    return this.displayName;
  }
}
```

Comment: your component doesn't show the `this.displayName` value assigned anywhere. So it makes sense for `console.log(this.AF.displayName)` to show properly while `console.log(this.displayName)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: I'm so sorry amal, I posted a version of the code that was edited. I will edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. Could you also please post your AFService if the question still remains?

Comment: Okay I have updated it. The service I haven't messed with much i tried adding a getDisplayName() function but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

So while I agree with the comment by amal and cant see where the `this.displayName` is set.  I have run into this problem before.  Since there is no previous component you will need a way for the page to save display name.  I usually use local storage to do this.

```
      localStorage.setItem('displayName',JSON.stringify(this.displayName));
```

To retrieve the data and

```
    this.displayName= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('displayName'));
```

To retrieve the data.  That being said I do not see where you are setting the domain name, which would cause a problem.  I am answering the general conceptual question you have about the refresh.

Comment: Legman thanks for the help. I've been trying to get around this problem for a while. Would you recommend that this is the "ideal" way to solve this issue?

Comment: I wouldn't say it the ideal solution, but it is the way I am dealing with it if that makes sense.  It should solve your problem, but there might be a more elegant way to handle this but at that point, it depends on how your overall app is set up.  So I would recommend it as a solution

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you should subscribe to auth service in your `AfService`

```
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.messages = this.db.list('messages');

    this.afAuth.auth.subscribe(res => {
        if (res && res.uid) {
          //user logged in
          this.email= res.email;
          this.displayName = res.displayName;
        } else {
          //user not logged in or logged out
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Now it is clear why you have `messages` available while `displayName` is not within your ChatComponent . In your AFService's constructor you are setting the value of `messages` but not for `displayName`. So while that service is instantiated within your ChatComponent, you are setting the component's `messages` and `displayName` properties to that from the AFService. But the AFService only has the value for `messages` within its own constructor. 
So the simple fix for your problem will be to have a value for `displayName` also defined within the service's constructor. 
If that value need to be fetched from somewhere else like asynchronously,  then you need to refactor either the component or the service's code based on that. 
Either way make sure you referring to some property of the AFService that is instantiated within its constructor while referring to it in the ChatComponent.